# OpenCart - how to disable image caching system?

Tags: caching, opencart, opencart2.x

Using the E-commerce platform OpenCart (PHP/MySQL-based).

Problem: the image caching is TERRIBLE. Not only do the images come out with visibly degraded quality, but the "cached" image size is actually larger. So, fail on both fronts.

Does anyone know how to disable the image cache in OpenCart 2.0.3.1 completely?

Comment: you can set the image size in admin image settings.  make sure your original images are at least as many pixels as what you're resizing to and the quality will be fine.

Comment: I'm not talking about changing the image size. That's not the problem. The problem that the OC caching engine RUINS the image quality. Even if the original is 2X-5X-10X the resolution, the end result looks horrible.

Comment: That hasn't been my experience Tom.  Can you please post a side by side image comparison to illustrate the issue you're seeing?

Comment: Opencart uses php's GD library and at the moment there are no known bugs that would result in the problems you described. I'm inclined to think your image rendering issues are due to some other unknown software issue.  Voting to close since the problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: OK, I'll provide some examples shortly.

Comment: Here we go. A high-res composite explaining what's happening.

http://imgur.com/a/VwABI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Tom.  I'll address a few things here regarding your example and then I'll attempt to actually answer your question.

(1) An image will never be transcoded if it is *exactly the same size* as the requested image.  See line 28 of **catalog/model/tool/image.php** where the block reads:

```
if ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height) {
    $image = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);
    $image->resize($width, $height);
    $image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
} else {
    copy(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image, DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
}
```

Not sure if you are familiar with php but that code effectively says:

> If the image height and width are the same as what's requested, then just copy the original into the cache and use it.

.  In your example you show a 500px x 500px image and the result of a 1:1 transcode.  That's simply not possible unless you've got 3rd party extensions altering the core methods here.

(2) The increase in size you're seeing could be the result of operating system meta data or a slightly less optimized jpg engine than what your graphics application has to offer. It could also be due to image content. In any event as your example demonstrates *it's negligible* - maybe around 1k.  In most cases the image engine will be able to reduce the size (see example below), but it really depends on a variety of factors.

(3) The quality differences you show would never be apparent in most cases.  You've presented what I'd consider to be an extreme case with delicate grayscale textures zoomed way in.  Any kind of lossy encoding or transcoding (jpg in this case) is likely to lose details like that.  That's the nature of lossy compression - you are discarding data in exchange for a smaller filesize.

In the following example i took a random image at 335px x 285px and resized it to 335px x 284px just as a demonstration.  For all intents and purposes, I can't see any degradation of quality here and the image size went from 32k down to 22k - a significantly smaller size:

**Original** (335px x 285px, 32k):

[image: http://zuma-design.com/shared/so/image-compare/kitten.jpg]

**Transcoded by Opencart** (335px x 284px, 22k):

[image: http://zuma-design.com/shared/so/image-compare/kitten-335x284.jpg]

With all that said, if you still feel that disabling the image cache is going to benefit your particular site, it would be extremely easy.  Look at **catalog/model/tool/image.php** and modify the `resize()` method to simply return the same filename it's passed:

```
public function resize($filename, $width, $height) {
    if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
        return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $filename;
    } else {
        return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $filename;
    }
}
```